# why does printing $( gives a number series

Tags: perl

When I started with variables to print a variable `$foo` in a string

I used `print ${foo}s` but when I used `print "$(foo)s"` 
it gave me

`1000 4 24 27 30 46 108 125 1000)s` . When I printed `$(` or `$)` it gives me the sequence `1000 4 24 27 30 46 108 125 1000` . Also 
`$[` gave `5.014002` and `$]` gave `0` . What do they mean?

Comment: `perldoc -v $(` (use quoting appropriate for your system if necessary) is a quick way to look up built-in variables.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$(` = The real gid of this process.

`$[` = This variable stores the index of the first element in an array, and of the first character in a substring. The default is 0.

`$)` = The effective gid of this process.

`$]` = Perlversion

seen here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html

Comment: Actually if you have `use 5.16.0` (or later) in your code `$[` can only ever be `0`, unless you load [arybase](https://metacpan.org/pod/arybase) with `use feature qw'arybase';` or explicitly with `use arybase;`.

Answer (score 7):

See [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) (in fact, see it any time you have a question about `$` followed by a symbol).

`$(` and `$)` give the real and effective gids of the process.

You get a space separated list of gids if the system supports membership in multiple groups simultaneously.

`$[` is the index considered to be the first element of an array.

`$]` is an old way to get the version of Perl being used to run the program.